# Trying to standardize/normalize data to go into CNN, but having issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, normalization

I have the following snippet of code and I'm trying to standardize/normalize the data before training my CNN.

```
X = [] # Image data
y = [] # Labels

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True)

Loops through imagepaths to load images and labels into arrays
for path in imagepaths:
  img = cv2.imread(path) # Reads image and returns np.array
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
  img = cv2.resize(img, (200, 200)) 
  img = datagen.standardize(img) #ERROR POINTING HERE
  X.append(img)

....
```

However, when running this I get the following error prompt pointing to the line I've commented above:

```
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Any idea on where I'm going wrong in standardizing? Or is there any easier way for me to standardize? I saw some solutions where people divide by 255, but I'm not sure exactly how to implement that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply `img_to_array` method:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

img = cv2.resize(img, (200, 200)) 
img = img_to_array(img)
img = datagen.standardize(img)
```